# Pull Request Build and skip other stages

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using multi stage YAML pipelines in Azure DevOps and Where I build in one stage and deploy the artifact to other stages. I have setup a Pull Request build and whenever a new code is pushed all stages in the pipeline are running, which is not desirable.

what i want is whenever a new code is pushed to any branch i want to run the build stage and skip the deploy stages. This option is available by default classic pipeline as build and release are a seperate component earlier

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add condition to skip stage/step for pull request builds. You can do using this

```
ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
```

```yaml
- stage: B
  condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    steps:
      - script: echo This is not PR trigger
```

You will fine more examples like this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#examples)